# Querying large amount of multidimensional points in R^N

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking at listing/counting the number of integer points in R^N (in the sense of Euclidean space), within certain geometric shapes, such as circles and ellipses, subject to various conditions, for small N. By this I mean that N < 5, and the conditions are polynomial inequalities.

As a concrete example, take R^2. One of the queries I might like to run is "How many integer points are there in an ellipse (parameterised by x = 4 cos(theta), y = 3 sin(theta) ), such that y * x^2 - x * y = 4?"

I could implement this in Haskell like this:

```
ghci> let latticePoints = [(x,y) | x <- [-4..4], y <-[-3..3], 9*x^2 + 16*y^2 <= 144, y*x^2 - x*y == 4]
```

and then I would have:

```
ghci> latticePoints
[(-1,2),(2,2)]
```

Which indeed answers my question.

Of course, this is a very naive implementation, but it demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve. (I'm also only using Haskell here as I feel it most directly expresses the underlying mathematical ideas.)

Now, if I had something like "In R^5, how many integer points are there in a 4-sphere of radius 1,000,000, satisfying x^3 - y + z = 20?", I might try something like this:

```
ghci> :{
Prelude| let latticePoints2 = [(x,y,z,w,v) | x <-[-1000..1000], y <- [-1000..1000],
Prelude|                      z <- [-1000..1000], w <- [-1000..1000], v <-[1000..1000],
Prelude|                      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 + v^2 <= 1000000, x^3 - y + z == 20]
Prelude| :}
```

so if I now type:

```
ghci> latticePoints2
```

Not much will happen...

I imagine the issue is because it's effectively looping through 2000^5 (32 quadrillion!) points, and it's clearly unreasonably of me to expect my computer to deal with that. I can't imagine doing a similar implementation in Python or C would help matters much either.

So if I want to tackle a large number of points in such a way, what would be my best bet in terms of general algorithms or data structures? I saw in another thread ([Count number of points inside a circle fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847310/count-number-of-points-inside-a-circle-fast)), someone mention quadtrees as well as K-D trees, but I wouldn't know how to implement those, nor how to appropriately query one once it was implemented.

I'm aware some of these numbers are quite large, but the biggest circles, ellipses, etc I'd be dealing with are of radius 10^12 (one trillion), and I certainly wouldn't need to deal with R^N with N > 5. If the above is NOT possible, I'd be interested to know what sort of numbers WOULD be feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to solve this problem. The problem of finding integer solutions to algebraic equations (equations of this sort are called [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)) is known to be undecidable. Apparently, you can write equations of this sort such that solving the equations ends up being equivalent to deciding whether a given Turing machine will halt on a given input.

In the examples you've listed, you've always constrained the points to be on some well-behaved shape, like an ellipse or a sphere. While this particular class of problem is definitely decidable, I'm skeptical that you can efficiently solve these problems for more complex curves. I suspect that it would be possible to construct short formulas that describe curves that are mostly empty but have a huge bounding box.

If you happen to know more about the structure of the problems you're trying to solve - for example, if you're always dealing with spheres or ellipses - then you may be able to find fast algorithms for this problem. In general, though, I don't think you'll be able to do much better than brute force. I'm willing to admit that (and in fact, hopeful that) someone will prove me wrong about this, though.

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks - I'm mainly interested in circles and ellipses, and I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the kd-tree method is that you recursive subdivide the search box and try to rule out whole boxes at a time. Given the current box, use some method that either (a) declares that all points in the box match the predicate (b) declares that no points in the box match the predicate (c) makes no declaration (one possibility, which may be particularly convenient in Haskell: [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic)). On (c), cut the box in half (say along the longest dimension) and recursively count in the halves. Obviously the method can choose (c) all the time, which devolves to brute force; the goal here is to do (a) or (b) as much as possible.

The performance of this method is very dependent on how it's instantiated. Try it -- it shouldn't be more than a couple dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

For nicely connected region, assuming your shape is significantly smaller than your containing search space, and given a seed point, you could do a growth/building algorithm:

```
Given a seed point:
Push seed point into test-queue
while test-queue has items:
    Pop item from test-queue
    If item tests to be within region (eg using a callback function):
        Add item to inside-set
        for each neighbour point (generated on the fly):
            if neighbour not in outside-set and neighbour not in inside-set:
               Add neighbour to test-queue
    else:
        Add item to outside-set
return inside-set
```

The trick is to find an initial seed point that is inside the function.

Make sure your `set` implementation gives O(1) duplicate checking. This method will eventually break down with large numbers of dimensions as the surface area exceeds the volume, but for 5 dimensions should be fine.